# node-smpp как получить статус?

Tags: node.js, smpp

node-smpp как получить статус сообщения? [Дефольтный](https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp) пример выводит только id сообщения, а как узнать статус доставки, ошибки и прочего?

Answer (score 1):

Элементарно,Ватсон. `console.log(pdu);`

Comment: Я все время получаю

     ` { command_length: 21,
            command_id: 2147483652,
            command_status: 0,
            sequence_number: 2,
            command: 'submit_sm_resp',
            message_id: '6020' }`

Меняется только message_id и command_length. Омтальные параметры остаются не изменными, для тестирования использую http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/

Comment: Как оказалось, нужно было добавить registered_delivery:1 в session.submit_sm и добавить слушателя session.on('deliver_sm', function(pdu) {